# Loop over complex data structure

Tags: yaml, jinja2

I'm using Ansible and Jinja2 to fill some configuration files. I'm trying to loop over a complex data structure but can't get it to print what I need.

This is an example of my data structure:

```
nodes:
  server-1:
    attrib1: value1
    containers:
      - name: container-1
        ip: 10.2.33.223
      - name: container-2
        ip: 10.2.33.239
  server-2:
    attrib1: value1
    containers:
      - name: container-3
        ip: 10.2.34.48
      - name: container-4
        ip: 10.2.34.50
```

This is the ansible playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - "vars/nodes.yml"
  tasks:
  - name: create configs
    template:
      src: "template.j2"
      dest: "config.cfg"
```

The jinja2 template would be something like this, but I can't get it right

```
{% for container in nodes.containers %}
  {{ container.name }}: {{ container.ip }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to get all the container names and IPs like this:

```
container-1: 10.2.33.223
container-2: 10.2.33.229
container-3: 10.2.34.48
container-4: 10.2.34.50
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing beats reading the documentation :)

This Jinja2 code gets me what I need from my data structure:

```
{% for key, value in nodes.iteritems() %}
  {% for container in value.containers %}
    {{ container.name }}: {{ container.ip }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I still need to fully understand the diferences between dictionaries and lists :)